# cheapest database-as-a-service for very small app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds, paas

I'm building an app for an organization with about 150 users. I expect the average user to do 20 r/w operations on the DB in a day. I've never used a DaaS commercially before and was surprised that with a mySQL instance on RDS, this would cost about 0.02 USD per hour, or 14.4 USD per month, for the least powerful DB, which is probably still much more powerful than what I would need. I couldn't find any conventional database that would be significantly cheaper.

On the other hand, DynamoDB with 1 RCU and 1 WCU seems to be promising to be much cheaper - to scale down better, so to say - than relational services.

I would still prefer a relational DB, however - are there any cheaper ones that I haven't found?

P.S. A VM in the cloud like lightsail, with mySQL installed, isn't an option - I don't want to administer the DB. I am also aware of the free tier for AWS but would prefer not using it for this.

Comment: You decision of DynamoDB versus RDS should be chosen based on access patterns, not cost.

Comment: yes, but the cost difference seems to be so unproportionally high that I'm considering being OK with a noSQL DB.

Comment: DynamoDB also seems to charge much less for on-demand as is seen here https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/, which would be only a few cents per month for me, in contrast to the $14 for a mySQL DB... Or am I misreading the numbers?

Comment: Haha good point, thanks for the illustration. I guess I'm just confused because the price difference seems so unproportional and I think I might have misinterpreted the numbers. Or haven't I?

Comment: OK thank you very much. This makes sense, I think I'll go with a SQL DB then.

Comment: [Aruba Cloud: MySQL 5.7 - DBAAS WITH SHARED RESOURCES](https://www.arubacloud.com/database-as-a-service/price-list.aspx): €0,50 / mo. for 1 GB of storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to inform you that found a standalone DB hosting plan for 10$/month at DigitalOcean added MySql support.

https://scalegrid.io/pricing.html?db=MYSQL&cloud=cloud_digital_ocean&replica=deployment_standalone&instance=Nano#section_pricing_dedicated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow pavlos. Please take the [tour] to understand that not all questions here are fit for answering, [help/on-topic]. I appreciate the effort to help with this question, but please learn about the larger goal here at StackOverflow, which is making a helpful Q/A collection according to certain rules, which make them useful for the people coming here. This question has been closed (very lately, it probably was only disvovered because of your post and you actually have earned gratitude for that) because it does not match. This is not easy to understand for a new user, I know.